# Is it possible to tell a Testclass that it shall be ran last?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I've written multiple classes inside a unit test project (visual studio unit test project) and it works fine except for one class. Due to how I get the connectionstring for my database access (I'm getting it in a way so that it will only be defined once at program start and not gotten again) the testclass which includes the routines for this hampers all other unit tests classes in their functionality if it is run before them.

Thus my question here is: Is it possible to tell a test class to be run last?

Comment: My opinion is that tests should be totally independent of each other. That kind of dependency should be avoided. Each class should have their own setup routines

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a suboptimal setup. Have you tried to do the necessary setup in an initialization method that you mark with the [AssemblyInitialize] attribute?
It will be run before all other test classes in the project. Notice that the signature of the method must be like below, and it must be put inside a class that is decorated with the [TestClass] attribute.

```
[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void Setup(TestContext context)
{
    // Store data in static variables, initialize database connection etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No - a test class is just a class containing unit tests. It has no information about what order it should be run. You could consider using an [ordered test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182630%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) if you want to control the order that tests run in.

In this case however it sounds like your "test" is really initialization logic for other tests. By doing initialization either in a [`TestInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx), [`ClassInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx) or [`AssemblyInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx) you should be able to make your tests run correctly regardless of the order in which they are run.

Answer (score 0):

> (I'm getting it in a way so that it will only be defined once at program start and not gotten again)

So you are using a static class/property, huh?

Something like this:

```
public class ConnectionStringProvider
{
    private static string _connectionString;

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (_connectionString == null)
                _connectionString = LoadConnectionString();
            return _connectionString; 
        }
    }

    private static void LoadConnectionString()
    {
        //fetch it from somewhere
    }

}
```

The easiest way to make it testable without changing the behavior is separate the API from the implementation. do that by creating a private instance of the class which you use in the property getter.

New implementation:

```
public class ConnectionStringProvider
{
    private static ConnectionStringProvider _instance;
    private string _connectionString;

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ConnectionStringProvider();
                _instance.LoadConnectionString();
            }

            return _instance._connectionString; 
        }
    }

    private void LoadConnectionString()
    {
        //fetch it from somewhere
    }

}
```

By doing so you can in your own tests create a new instance of the class without changing the static property:

In your business code:

```
var conStr = ConnectionStringProvider.ConnectionString;
```

In your test methods:

```
[Fact]
public void load_connection_if_not_accessed_previously
{

    var sut = new ConnectionStringProvider();
    // [.. test here.. ]
}
```

That way you can still test the implementation without affecting the other tests.